Issues Creating Windows Installer for Electron App with Electron-Builder and Reducing Application Size
I'm having trouble creating a Windows installer for my Electron app using electron-builder. My app is built with React, and I've configured my package.json scripts to handle the build and packaging process. Additionally, I need to reduce the application size from 102 MB to around 50 MB. Despite following the documentation, the installer creation doesn't work as expected, and the application size remains too large.
I set up the following scripts in my package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "package": "electron-builder",
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000 && electron .\""
  }
}

My electron-builder configuration in package.json looks like this:
{
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myapplication.timetrackerapp",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg.dll"
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "dmg",
        "zip"
      ],
      "icon": "build/macIcon.icns",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb",
        "snap"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.png",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg"
      ],
      "category": "Utility"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }
}

What I've Tried:

Minimizing Dependencies: I've reviewed my package.json to remove unnecessary dependencies and devDependencies.
Tree Shaking: Ensured my Webpack configuration (used by React) supports tree shaking to eliminate unused code.
Code Splitting: Implemented code splitting to load only necessary parts of the application.
Compression: Used compression techniques like uglify-js for JavaScript files and sharp for image files.
Electron Packaging: Followed best practices for Electron packaging as mentioned in various resources.

Expected vs. Actual Results:

Expected: The application size should reduce significantly, ideally around 50 MB, and the Windows installer should be created successfully.
Actual: The application size remains at 102 MB, and the installer creation process either fails or results in an unexpectedly large installer.

Additional Details:

Node.js Version: v14.x
Electron Version: v13.x
Operating System: Windows 10

Here is my package.json for additional context:
{
  "name": "My Application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application",
  "author": {
    "email": "my.application@gmail.com",
  },
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "sound-play": "^1.1.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.21"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "package": "electron-builder",
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000 && electron .\""
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myapp.timetrackerapp",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg.dll"
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "dmg",
        "zip"
      ],
      "icon": "build/macIcon.icns",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb",
        "snap"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.png",
      "extraFiles": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/ffmpeg"
      ],
      "category": "Utility"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^28.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.12.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}



Well, don't forget that your Electron application actually has to include a full copy of Chromium. I checked one of my apps and sure enough, its Windows installer is 102.4 MiB in size. Packed as a ZIP it's 137.4 MiB though. So I guess that's already the minimum size of Electron apps? Could you please [edit] your question to include any error messages you get when installer creation "fails"?

Also, anything listed as a devDependency doesn't contribute to the final build, so there's no need to thin these down.
